# What is the attribute that holds encrypted password in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, attributes, passwords

I just created Windows 10 instance via amazon workspaces and it is connected to simple AD. This AD handles authentication by verifying my username and password.

I see my entry from the directory and I do see other user security attributes like `badPwdCount` but I don't see any attribute may hold an encrypted password.

Reading upon Microsoft documentation, either `userPassword` or `unicodePwd` attribute I should search for but I don't see either of them.

I would greatly appreciate if you could guide me what attribute I should search for or how to view it? I use AD Explorer program to access the AD for read operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `userPassword` or `unicodePwd` in a query, or get that data in any way. They can only be used to change the password.

The documentation for each describes how they're used to do that: [`userPassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223249.aspx), [`unicodePwd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx)

Comment: Ty for taking time answering my question. It sounds like there is no attribute visible in AD for displaying encrypted password. Did I understand correctly? I understand what you mean by `userPassword` or `uniocdPwd` for password change only. I am a bit familiar with Oracle's ldap implementation (OUD), in there I see an attribute that holds encrypted passwd. I am just exploring in AD context as newbie, trying to have somehow understanding of how it maps/displays such data.

Comment: Correct - there is no way for you to view the encrypted password of a user in AD.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you just need to authenticate a user?

Comment: At the moment, the objective would be comparing AD with existing OUD in our shop. I was able to authenticate myself to log into Windows 10 (amazon workspaces) and just want to view which attribute maps to user entered password. I see my login name in `cn`, `name`, `sAMAccountName` however I couldn't find any attr maps to encrypted password I provided to login.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am authentcating the existing users successfully but unable to authenticate the user that is created from my code(LDAP). Although the users are created in the AD. Will you please tell me how to add userPassword in the AD? how to authenticate these users ?